# increment values in a numpy array multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to increment values in a numpy array multiple times. For example I would like to do:

```
input = np.array([[1,1],[2,2]])
input[[0,0,0],[1,0,1]] += [4,1,6]
```

and get output:

`array([[2, 11],
       [2, 2]])`

However, numpy gives

`array([[2, 7],
       [2, 2]])`

Is there a way to increment the same index multiple times?